How to create a $2 \times 2$ table based on nested if-else condition?
I have 2 variables $A$ and $B$
$A$ is a numeric variable with starting value of $A$ is x.
$B$ is a categorical variable with categories $p, q, r,s$
Now based on below condition the final value of $A$ to be derived. The conditions are as follows,

If $B = p$ and $A < 8$ then final value of $A$ will be 100
if $B = p$ OR $q$ and $A \ge 6$ then final value of $A$ will be $x + 10$
if $B = q$ and $A < 6$ then final value of $A$ will be 200
if $V = s$ then final value of $A$ will be $x - 10$
else final value of $A$ will be $x$

Based on the below information, I would like to build a two way table like below

Is there any way to build such table based on the available information?

If $B = \mathrm p$ and $A = 7$, is the final value $100$ or is it $17$?

@Tzimmo It is a waterfall logic. Therefore for your case the first condition will trigger hence final value of A will be 100

Your first step in building the table should be to remove overlaps like this. Then go through each value of $B$ in order. Where exactly are you having problems?

@Tzimmo From implementation pov I dont see any issue in above waterfall logic. I am trying to build a two way table to build some standard statistical model. Also presenting the rule in two-way table would be visually more fitting
